# How to toggle button size?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on VBA code for a command button. The button needs to shrink (hide) after being clicked, then the print dialog appears, and then after printing, the button needs to return to it's normal size.

The first two parts work.

Getting the button to return to it's correct size after printing isn't working.

I'm calling iShp twice which is causing errors.

```vb
Dim iShp As Word.InlineShape
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If iShp.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "cmdSaveCert" Then
        iShp.Width = 1
        iShp.Height = 1
    End If
Next
    
With ActiveDocument
    Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show   'allows user to select Printer
End With

Dim iShp As Word.InlineShape
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If iShp.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "cmdSaveCert" Then
        iShp.Width = 28185
        iShp.Height = 13710
    End If
```

Comment: Please add the Sub...End Sub lines - it's not clear whether this is a single procedure or more than one. If one, don't "Dim" iShp again, just use it (IOW comment out the second `Dim` line and test).

Comment: Place your Dim statements at the top of your procedure where they belong, not in the code. Then you will see that you declare `iShp` twice which causes an error, and rightly so. Once declared you can use the same variable multiple times within its scope, here presumed to be one procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips!  Combining advice from both of you got my code working right.  I had to toss a 'Next' below the last 'End If' statement to get everything working right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Type SizeCache
    width As Integer
    height As Integer
End Type

Private Sub ShowPrintDialog(Optional ByVal doc As Document)
    Dim wasProtected As Boolean
    Dim currentShape As InlineShape
    Dim dimensions() As SizeCache, size As Long, entry As SizeCache
    ' Prepare Document
    If doc Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = ThisDocument
    End If
    If doc.ProtectionType = wdAllowOnlyFormFields Then
        wasProtected = True
        doc.Unprotect
    End If
    ' Hide all buttons
    For Each currentShape In doc.InlineShapes
        If Not currentShape.OLEFormat Is Nothing Then
            entry.width = currentShape.width
            entry.height = currentShape.height
            size = size + 1
            ReDim Preserve dimensions(size)
            dimensions(size) = entry
            With dimensions(UBound(dimensions))
                Debug.Print currentShape.OLEFormat.Object.Name & ": " & .width & "x" & .height
            End With
            currentShape.width = 1
            currentShape.height = 1
        End If
    Next
    '
    ' At last, allows user to select Printer and print
    '
    Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show
    ' Restore all buttons
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    For Each currentShape In doc.InlineShapes
        If Not currentShape.OLEFormat Is Nothing Then
            With dimensions(i)
                currentShape.width = .width
                currentShape.height = .height
            End With
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    ' Restore Document
    If wasProtected Then
        doc.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, True
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call ShowPrintDialog
End Sub
```